# How to check ,Particular Element is available on page or not in selenium Web driver?

Tags: selenium, web, driver, element

I Need your help.Let me describe you my scenario.

I have a login form and 10+ Email,same passwords. I have to write a automation script which took one Email id and password and enter in Login form.If Email id correct than allowed to User go inside in application and shows a "Logout" Link.if Email id is incorrect than show a message "Entered correct Email id and password". **Now problem is How i write (IF Condition) to check either allowed to login and not allowed to login because if suppose i wrote if condition for not allowed to login and entered Login id and password is correct than it shows a error message due to failed IF condition.**

I tried to write code:

```
enter code here

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class LoginCheckofProcuretiger {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static WebElement web;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        driver.navigate().to("https://eprocure.procuretiger.com/EPROCP");

        }

        @AfterClass
        public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        //driver.close();
        }

    @Test
    public void test() {


        String Mytest[] ={
                    "bidder1A@abcprocure.com",
                    "bidderAB@abcprocure.com",
                    "bidderAC@abcprocure.com",
                    "bidderAD@abcprocure.com",
                    "bidderAE@abcprocure.com",
                    "bidderAF@abcprocure.com",

                    "bidderDK@abcprocure.com",
                    "bidderDL@abcprocure.com",
                    "bidderDM@abcprocure.com"
                };

        int i;
        for( i=0;i<Mytest.length;i++ ){

            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys(Mytest[i]);
            driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).sendKeys("auction@123");
            driver.findElement(By.name("btnlogin")).click();
            if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//fieldset/div[@class='errorMsg t_space']")).getText() != null)
            {
                System.out.println("User Not allowed to access. " +Mytest[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Home")).click();
            System.out.println("User allowed to access. " +Mytest[i]);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of if-else you need to use try/catch and test only the presence of Logout link. Haven't tested this code, but i think it should work.

```
try{
 driver.findElement(Logout link locator);
 System.out.println("User is allowed access");
 .....
}catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println("User is NOT allowed access");
  .....
 }finally{
  .....
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use this (see below) because it takes longer when using `try{}catch{}`

```
elem = driver.findElements(locator);

if (elem.Count > 0)
{
   //Allowed
}
else
{
   //Not allowed
}
```

Comment: I used such of code but it was not working. thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

It's incredibly slow (and not very elegant) to use (1) try/catch for findElement or (2) count>0 for findElements

It's best to write a check on a case-by-case basis

For example, let's say your login form has either

```
(1) <input class="can_login"> or (2) <input class="no_login">
```

To do a faster check than try/catch of count>0, do something like (in Python):

```
list_of_input_classes = [ elem.get_attribute('class') for elem in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("form#login > input") ]

if "can_login" in list_of_input_classes:
   #you can login
elif "no_login" in list_of_input_classes:
   #you can't login
else:
   raise Exception( "why were neither of these options found? i.e. unexpected result" )
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.I will try to using this one process.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and its working

```
try{ 
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login")).click(); 
    driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys(LoginIDs[i]);
    driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).sendKeys(Password[i]);
    driver.findElement(By.name("btnlogin")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")).click();
} catch(Exception e) { 
    System.out.println("Login with "+ LoginIDs[i] + " : Failed");
} finally { 
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Home")).click(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import jxl.Workbook;
    import jxl.write.WritableCell;
    import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
    import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
    import jxl.write.WriteException;
    import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;

    import org.junit.AfterClass;
    import org.junit.BeforeClass;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    import com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos.FieldDescriptorProto.Label;


    public class ExportinExcel {
        public static WebDriver driver;
        @BeforeClass
        public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
            //driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        //  driver.navigate().to("URL");
            //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        }

        @AfterClass
        public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        }

        @Test
        public void test() throws IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException {
            //fail("Not yet implemented");
            // Given the path where to store Excel.
File FExcel = new File("D:\\software\\Excel\\createExcel.xls");
                 /* Create a Workbook. */
            WritableWorkbook workbookexcel= Workbook.createWorkbook(FExcel);
                 /* Create a Worksheet. */
            workbookexcel.createSheet("Data", 0);
            WritableSheet writeablesheet= workbookexcel.getSheet(0);
                /* Add Content in row and column and here coumn value increment each time.   */  
        int i=0,j=0;
            for(;j<tablecontent.lenght();j++){
            jxl.write.Label Data1 = new jxl.write.Label(i, j, "Enter Path of Table data");
            writeablesheet.addCell(Data1);}

            /*jxl.write.Label Data2 = new jxl.write.Label(i, j, "Enter Path of Table data");
            writeablesheet.addCell(Data2);*/

workbookexcel.write();
            workbookexcel.close();
        }

    }**
```

Answer (score 0):

```
accept
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import jxl.Workbook;
    import jxl.write.WritableCell;
    import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
    import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
    import jxl.write.WriteException;
    import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;

    import org.junit.AfterClass;
    import org.junit.BeforeClass;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    import com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos.FieldDescriptorProto.Label;


    public class ExportinExcel {
        public static WebDriver driver;
        @BeforeClass
        public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
            //driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        //  driver.navigate().to("http://www.indianrail.gov.in/tatkal_Scheme.html");
            //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        }

        @AfterClass
        public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        }

        @Test
        public void test() throws IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException {
            //fail("Not yet implemented");
            // Given the path where to store Excel.
File FExcel = new File("D:\\software\\Excel\\createExcel.xls");
                 /* Create a Workbook. */
            WritableWorkbook workbookexcel= Workbook.createWorkbook(FExcel);
                 /* Create a Worksheet. */
            workbookexcel.createSheet("Data", 0);
            WritableSheet writeablesheet= workbookexcel.getSheet(0);
                /* Add Content in row and column and here coumn value increment each time.   */  

            jxl.write.Label Data1 = new jxl.write.Label(0, 0, driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//tr[1]/td[1]/p/b/span")).gettext() );
            writeablesheet.addCell(Data1);
            jxl.write.Label Data2 = new jxl.write.Label(0, 1, driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//tr[1]/td[2]/p/b/span")).gettext() );
            writeablesheet.addCell(Data2);
            jxl.write.Label Data3 = new jxl.write.Label(0, 2, driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//tr[1]/td[3]/p/b/span")).gettext() );
            writeablesheet.addCell(Data3);
            jxl.write.Label Data4 = new jxl.write.Label(1, 0, driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//tr[2]/td[1]/p/b/span")).gettext() );
            writeablesheet.addCell(Data4);
            jxl.write.Label Data5 = new jxl.write.Label(1, 1, driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//tr[2]/td[2]/p/b/span")).gettext() );
            writeablesheet.addCell(Data5);
            jxl.write.Label Data6 = new jxl.write.Label(1, 2, driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//tr[2]/td[3]/p/b/span")).gettext() );
            writeablesheet.addCell(Data6);

workbookexcel.write();
            workbookexcel.close();
        }
/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/p/b/span
    .//tr[1]/td[1]/p/b/span
    .//tr[1]/td[2]/p/b/span
```